# Ошибка в консоли при выводе примера из книги про js

Tags: javascript

при выводе примера из книге по js у меня произошла ошибка .

```
var opportunitiesFunction = function (name){
   conosle.log("Привет, "+" name "+ "!"); 
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас опечатка: conosle вместо console

Comment: И по идее `" name "` должно быть без кавычек, это же имя переменной: `conosle.log("Привет, " + name + "!"); `

Answer (score 3):

```
var opportunitiesFunction = function (name){
   console.log("Привет, "+ name + "!"); // ты conosle.log написал
};
```

Comment: если ответ помог, пометь его как решение